# BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard to expose schemas as WCF service issue?

Tags: wcf, schema, biztalk, publish, biztalk2006r2

We are about to expose schemas as WCF service using the BizTalk WCF Publishing wizard. We have a bunch of schemas in an .dll file. However, when we choose request-response operations and selects a schema type only a few schemas is select-able in the dialog.

The schemas that are not select-able have two possible root elements (i.e., both request and response element are defined within the schema). Could this be the issue?

We are using BizTalk 2006 R2, Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, never mind.

When using BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard to expose shemas, make sure you GAC the .dll containing the shemas first..